# Sub-sites not showing in quick launch

Tags: 2013, quick-launch, sub-site

It seems like some functionality changed between Moss 2007 and our new SharePoint 2013 site,

Is there a easy way to list sub sites into the quick launch automatically or as an alternative create a list that I can display as a web part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to activate the publishing feature:

> **Activate publishing at the site collection level**
>
> 1.From the root of your site collection, click Settings Small Settings gear that took the place of Site Settings. > Site settings.
>
> 2.On the Site Settings page under Site Collection Administration, click Site collection features.
>
> 3.On the Site Features page, scroll down to SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure and click Activate.
>
> Once publishing features are activated, subsites inherit them
>   automatically. But, if you built a site before activating the
>   publishing infrastructure, you’ll have to manually activate it for
>   each site.
>
> **Activate publishing at the site level**
>
> 1.From any page within the site, click (gear icon) Settings Small Settings gear that took the place of Site Settings. > Site settings.
>
> 2.On the Site Settings page, in the Site Actions section, click Manage site features.
>
> 3.On the Site Features page, next to SharePoint Server Publishing, click Activate.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/enable-publishing-features-HA102802294.aspx